# Pokemon Quest: Purchases carried over?

Tags: pokemon-quest

What happens to in-app purchases if I delete the Pokemon quest app, redownload it, and start a new game?

Comment: Do you mean in-app purchases as in Decorations, which are bought with PM Tickets, or the packs which you buy with real money?